# Phase View, 3D Room in autodesk forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-data-management

In the new Docs 360, there is the phase view on the left side.

[Phase image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTrqB.png)

In this project, the phases are bounded together on a single document, but on other project, the phases are created as a seperate revit document which I assume to be related to the size involved for each view(is this true?). On testing , these seperated revit phase document are not viewable on forge web-api (the error i received is GET /api/manifest call failed Not Found). The question is, Would it be possible to replicate the phase view in Forge? And if no How do I open the seperate revit phase document created when uploading to cloud.

And in previous question I've asked about the possibility of getting room information in forge which I've been told to be impossible. Upon inspecting the phase view in docs, I've come to notice that there is the Room element exist (clickable etc etc). Is this a bug ? If no, does bringing phase view to the forge web app will allow me to click on room element?

[Room Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dZcC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have talked with our engineering team, and learnt that the room/space are exported by Revit extractor now. But currently, they are only supported in BIM360 Docs, not in Forge Viewer unfortunately.

Comment: what about the phases? is it possible to view phases in the forge viewer?

Comment: I am not clear about phases, is this an element in Revit like Room/Space? Can you give more details?

Comment: Its the attribute of an element in revit. Its under Phasing where it has a phase filter and phase. In revit you can filter the element by phase.

Comment: I believe the phase is in the same situation as Room/Space, not be in public Forge viewer yet.

Comment: Some more finding, you can get the phase information from Get properties API or viewer client, but Forge Viewer does not do anything special for phase, you need to do that by yourself if you want.

Comment: thank you very much i'll try to deal with it somehow